# How do I get the current row index of my table using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, foreach

So I am trying to get the row index of my table using Jquery, however my code returns the same index number for every single row. I need to find the index to remove the selected row. However this code only removes the last value
What I have tried so far:

```
function updateCredentialList() {
    var index = $('.existingCredential').find('tr').closest('tr').index();
    var i = $('.existingCredential').find('tr:eq('+index+')').remove();
    alert(index);   
 }
```

My table:

```
<c:choose>
            <c:when test="${action == 'edit'}"> 
            <td class="data">
            <input type="hidden" name="pkAdminCredentials" value="${environment.pkAdminCredentialIds}">
            <input type="hidden" name="dbCredentials" value="${environment.dbCredentialIds}">
            <table class="existingCredential">
            <tr>
                <th>Primary?</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="each" items="${environment.pkAdminCredentials}">
            <tr>
                <td class="edit">${each.primary ? 'Yes' : 'No'</td>
                <td class="edit">${each.username}</td>
                <td class="edit">${each.password}</td>
                <td class="edit">${each.id}</td>
                <td><a class="editCredential" class="openWindow" data-modal-id="existingCredential" data-credential-id="${each.id}">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </table>
            </td>
            </c:when>
 </c:choose>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get current index using jQuery one possibility is the function [index](https://api.jquery.com/index/).

Let's create a simple table with 3 rows and an onclick event handler for each row:

```js
$(function () {
  
  $('table').find('tr').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).data('isSelected', true);
    $(this).siblings().data('isSelected', false);
    $('#log').append('<p>Current Index Row is: ' + $('table').find('tr').index(this) + '</p>')
  });


  $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    var selectedRow = $('table').find('tr').filter(function(index, element) {
      return $(this).data('isSelected') == true;
    });
    if (selectedRow.length == 1) {
      selectedRow.remove();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>u1</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>100</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>Click on a table row</p>
<button id="btn">Remove the selected ROW (click on it before)</button>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However `$('table').find('tr').index(this)` won't work in my code(it just returns -1). I am wondering is it due to the for each?
Also `$('table').find('tr').index()` just returns 7(the last index in my case)`

Comment: @EoghanBuckey Snippet updated with a remove button: it's an idea for you on how to implement the row deletion. I hope this could help you

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This worked absolutely perfect with a few minor edits to the selectors etc.